# Remove unescape characters and format json

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind, objectmapper

How can I transform this:

```json
"parameters" : [ "{name:\"xx\", value:\"45\",typRef:\"FE\",unit:\"grad\"}" ],
```

to this:

```json
"parameters" : [ {
        "name" : "xx",
        "value" : "45",
        "typRef" : "FE",      
        "unit" : "grad"
        }]
```

I use the objectMapper to write as String

```java
public class ParameterClass 
   {
      @NonNull private final String name;
      @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL) private final String value;
      @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL) private final typRef;
      @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL) private final String unit;

      private ParameterClass (@NonNull String name, String value, String typRef, String unit)
      {
         this.name = name;
         this.value = value;
         this.typRef = typRef;
         this.unit = unit;
      }
```

The method to build a json

```java
buildAsJson(String name, String unit, ...) {
ParameterClass parameter = new ParameterClass(name, unit, ..);
return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(parameter);
}
```

I collect all into a list:

```java
List<String> parameters = List.of(buildAsJson("xx", "45", ...), buildAsJson(...))
```

Comment: This is a bit unclear. Is the original value an object where `parameters` contain a list of strings, where each value is a string containing json?

Comment: Please give a complete, runnable example which illustrates the problem.

Comment: You shouldn't serialize the individual `ParameterClass` instances to JSON and the serialize a list of those strings, you should collect the `ParameterClass` instances in a list and serialize the list as a whole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store the string `parameter`, then read that JSON string with `objectMapper.readTree(...)`. It will convert the JSON string to valid JSON format if the JSON string is valid.

```java
JsonNode buildAsJson(String name, String unit, ...) {
  ParameterClass parameter = new ParameterClass(name, unit, ..);
  String parameter = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(parameter);
  return objectMapper.readTree(parameter);
}
```